# how does IE find registered activex control

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, activex

I am building a activex control with qt. If I register it as `control-name.exe /regserver`, IE11 can load it. And register entries was writen to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. But user of this activex control do not have admin rights, so I am struggling to register this com server on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` level.

I have tried export entries under the `CLSID` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` path to a reg file, and replace `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, then import this reg file back (and delete other entries with the same `CLSID`). But IE11 could not find the activex control. Does this mean IE11 does not look for `CLSID` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, but only `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`?

I have read some posts and articles, but still not sure whether this idea, as '**register com server without admin rights for IE to load**', is achievable. For example, if I found a way to put every registry into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (still working on it), could IE load my activex control?

Any help? Thanks in advance.

**update**:
This is how I did the test:

1. run `control-name.exe /regserver` with admin user
2. export registry to `.reg` files then delete these registry.
3. change `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`  and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`  to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
4. login with a user without admin rights and double click these `.reg` files.

I searched registry with RegCool and saw the registry are all under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/S-1-00.../...`. (`S-1-00...` is a serial of numbers).

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Cloud you please give me a tip about how to add ActiveX controls to this `Administrator Approved Controls` list?

Comment: It seems like my previous suggestion can only work if the user manually adds ActiveX control. Here, I want to confirm with you whether you had refreshed the registry after creating the registry under the current user? It can be possible that changes not get applied until you refresh it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I update the post, I guess this is a lousy hack. I am trying other ways to solve this. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Does the user accounts has permission to access the folder from where you are trying to install the control as an admin? If not, then for testing purposes try to grant permission and see whether it works for users or not.

Comment: It turns out client's company does limit permissions on program and folders. After approved by their system admin, it worked.

Comment: From your previous comment, it looks like granting the permissions to the programs and folders helped to fix the issue. I have posted my previous comment as an answer to this question. You can try to mark the helpful answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check whether the user accounts has permission to access the folder from where you are trying to install the control as an admin? If not, then for testing purposes try to grant permission and see whether it works for users or not.

Comment: I think the way I export, modify and reimport register entries is a lousy shortcut (and I really could not understand how windows system work internally). And apparently permissions is the right way.